# How to access SBT settings from Java code in PlayFramework?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, sbt, sbt-buildinfo

I have a PlayFramework application, and there is a `name` and `version` in the `build.sbt`.

If I run the play console, I can access this information by typing `name` or `version`.

How can I get this information from Java code inside the application? I can't seem to find any useful methods in `Play.application()` and I have not been able to find this in the documentation.

Comment: You might want to rename this to "How to access SBT settings from Java code?"

Comment: You use Play 2.2, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you can use the SBT plugin [BuildInfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo):

Add to project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.2.5")
```

And to build.sbt:

```
buildInfoSettings

sourceGenerators in Compile <+= buildInfo

buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion)

buildInfoPackage := "hello"
```

Now you can access the build information with static methods:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(hello.BuildInfo.name());//the name of the application as output
    }

}
```

Comment: I see that this works, but what in the world is `hello`? Is it a static member of `Controller`? What makes it available in the `index` method?

Comment: You can set the package of the genarated class in build.sbt with buildInfoPackage := "hello"